# Temporary files - Generating a unique ID with time

Tags: time, concurrency, system, unique

In order to give and identifier to temporary files, I want to implement a system call on linux which will return a unique identifier. More importantly, my system call should return a unique value even when it is used by concurrently by different processes.
I have thought about using the current date and time, but I am not sure concurrent calls will get a different identifier.
Would it be enough to take a very precise time into account (like microsecond for example) in order to get different times?

Comment: [`mkstemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkstemp)?

Comment: You could append a time-stamp with the process id and use that value..

Comment: "using the current date and time" is not sufficient. You'll need some synchronization or atomic operation to guarantee you are unique. For that, you can repeat generating 'random' filenames and try to [open()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) a file with `O_EXCL | O_CREAT` until it succeeds.